# Prove or disprove: There exists an integer $k\geq 4$ such that $2k^2 -5k+2$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove or disprove: There exists an integer $k\geq 4$ such that $2k^2 -5k+2$ is a prime number.

If true (which I'm pretty sure it isn't), then the proof needs to be in either contradiction or contraposition.

Comment: The question appeared as a homework problem and we know full well there is no reliable prime generator formula therefore either the prime doesn't exist or algebraic manipulation will reveal the prime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** $$2k^2-5k+2=(2k-1)(k-2){}$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. I will edit it

Comment: Ah, just had a hard time wrapping my head around it.  Obv, if k >= 4, 4-2=2, therefore (2k-1)(k-2) are both greater than 1, so 2k^2 -5k+2 can't be prime (a number divisible only by 1 and itself).